# Flask: how does gevent.pywsgi differ from usgi w.r.t. os forking?

Tags: python, flask, gevent

I have a Flask application that uses a messaging library that is NOT process safe (multiple processes using the same pointer results in a `panic: not fork-reentrant` error)

I've noticed that there is a large difference between the options on this flask page: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/deploying/wsgi-standalone/

Gevent works for my application. I never get into a panic.

UWSGI does not work for my application; it panics as soon as the second request comes in.

Is the following understanding correct then?
Gevent works using greenlet which is a coutourtine library, but it executes all within a single process.
UWSGI launches a new process for each incoming request, so upon the second request, a process is launched and the shared memory is access which causes the panic.

I guess my high level question is what the exact difference between `uwsgi` and `gevent.pywsgi` is>?

Comment: What is your uwsgi config?

Comment: @Fian I am using this project, and it seems to have a VERY terse uwsgi: https://github.com/tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask-docker/blob/master/python3.7/app/uwsgi.ini